# Cannot store SELECT query into PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to store a query result in order to use it in another SELECT statement but it isn't working..

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$result = "SELECT sensorid FROM users WHERE username = '$username' ";
```

$result is supposed to have an integer but how can I use that variable into another select like...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sensor WHERE sensorid = '$result'";
```

Comment: You need to execute the query using your favourite mysql api. $ result is just a string

Comment: How is `$result` supposed to be an integer? The variable contains just the string you assigned it. If you want to execute the query, you need to do that with your favourite DBMS API (like PDO). https://secure.php.net/pdo

Answer (score 0):

You need to join users table with sensor table on sensorid column.

```
$query = "select s.* from users u join sensor s on s.id = u.sensorid where u.username = $username"
```

See [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0ecda/1)